# Eclipse checkstyle plugin - Can I customize my .xml to apply different max value checks for java files?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, legacy-code

Is it possible to customize my .xml file(s) in Eclipse Kepler to accomplish the task I've outlined below? If yes, then how is it done?

Here is my specific example scenario to help provide context.

Currently my Eclipse IDE has checkstyle warnings set up for code violations like NPathComplexity, ClassFanOutComplexity, CyclomaticComplexity, StrictDuplicateCode, FileLength, inside the checkstyle.xml file.

I have a legacy java file where ClassFanOutComplexity has 44 violations, but the max value for CFOC violations is set to 27 inside checkstyle.xml.

Several other legacy java files with the same checkstyle problem have violations exceeding the max of 27 (33, 29, 55, etc.). All these files contain tested legacy java code that works as intended. My task with the legacy java is to, without refactoring/changing the code base, set up checkstyle to make sure that each violation in each java file does NOT exceed the CURRENT number of violations and suppress these warnings until they exceed their current number of violations.

Basically, I need to suppress current violations for legacy java files, but need checkstyle to throw a warning if (in the future) these files exceed their current number of violations.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. I think your question has an answer here: [Checkstyle different rules for different files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25894431/1005481)

Comment: That's interesting, Thomas. However, after reading the answer I'm still not clear/grokking how to apply that solution to my specific example given these constraints. Can someone else offer a solution that directly addresses the specific context of my problem?