# How to execute a maven plugin twice with different property

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I would like to build from a maven pom running two sequential executions of the same plugin, in the same phase differing only by a single property, which will result in two different archives being created.  Since the configuration is rather complicated, I'd rather NOT copy it just to change one value, which would create a maintenance nightmare.  If it was somehow possible to define such a property in the `<executions>` section of the plugin config, I could avoid this headache.

**Question**: Is this possible and if so how?

**Update**: Two answers have mentioned using multiple executions and one of them mentions that you can have separate configurations in each execution. But given that the majority of my configuration is constant between the two executions, can I have one configuration on the plugin level and also have configuration sections in each execution for the parts that are different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke the same maven build twice in one call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239786/how-to-invoke-the-same-maven-build-twice-in-one-call)

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question I would say

Comment: @Steve check my answer, yes, it gets exactly to your point (clarified in your update)

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo Ive tried to use your solution for my own problem but seems to make no diffrenence, could you help please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299040/how-do-i-make-this-maven-pom-have-two-profiles-only-difference-being-in-mainclas

Comment: try gradle.  These kinds of issues drove me away from using maven to build rpms :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Given the simple Maven Source Plugin configuration (as an example) you have a shared configuration across all of its executions (outside the `executions` element) and then a custom configuration per each execution, for the same phase, as requested by your question:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <includePom>true</includePom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-id1</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>aaa</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-id2</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <finalName>bbb</finalName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The configuration entry `<includePom>true</includePom>` will in this case be merged with the custom configurations of each execution and as such centralize the common configuration as plugin generic configuration.

For more details on the different level of configurations, you can check official Maven documentation, [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html), in particular the example "Configuring compile to run twice". Further details are also available on the official POM documentation, [here](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins), Plugins section.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have provided the answer to my update question.  You seem to be saying that it is possible to define one configuration for the whole plugin (containing the constant items) and separate configurations in the executions (containing the per-execution differences).  Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Exactly, I just tested the snippet I posted before adding it to my answer and it works perfectly. I will link soon the official documentation (which I read a while ago exactly about this point).

Comment: concerned Official documentation link added.

Comment: I'd still like to know the significance in the "options" in the official documentation.  They seem useless to me.

Comment: And it's still not as nice as being able to define different properties between the two executions.

Comment: Further official documentation about plugin configuration here https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugins speaking in that case about merging between parent and child pom, but it would be the same about generic plugin configuration and execution configuration

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a different execution (still bound to the same phase)

To avoid duplication of the config, you can put the `<configuration>` outside the `<execution>` element and then in the 2 executions, you only define the property that is different.

Taken from the maven [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag):

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-myquery-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>execution1</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <configuration>
              <url>http://www.foo.com/query</url>
              <timeout>10</timeout>
              <options>
                <option>one</option>
                <option>two</option>
                <option>three</option>
              </options>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>query</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>execution2</id>
            <configuration>
              <url>http://www.bar.com/query</url>
              <timeout>15</timeout>
              <options>
                <option>four</option>
                <option>five</option>
                <option>six</option>
              </options>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>query</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I saw this documentation, but I don't understand from it what the significance of the "options" is.  How are they used?  The example doesn't show that.  A property has a name and a value, but an option doesn't seem to.

Comment: Hi Steve, I think I don't fully understand your question then. Could you clarify what bits are not clear? ... and have your tried reading the whole page that is linked? As it does explain how plugins are configured and how the configuration is inherited.

Comment: going to clarify question.

Answer (score 2):

You create two <execution> elements within the <plugin> declaration.  Each <execution> element can have it's own <configuration> section.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create a jar and a put in in a zip file with other config files 
This worked for me

```html
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.1</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
     <id>build-jar-with_dep1</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
       <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
       </descriptorRefs>
       <finalName>${buildversion}</finalName>
       <finalName>finalname</finalName>
       <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
                         <goal>assembly</goal>
                     </goals>
     </execution>
     <execution>
     <id>build_zip1</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <configuration>
       <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
       <finalName>${buildversion}</finalName>
       <finalName>finalname</finalName>
       <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
                         <goal>single</goal>
                     </goals>
     </execution>
   
    </executions>
   </plugin>
```

Comment: Hi - welcome to stack overflow. Could you add some details about why this works/