# Launching more than one Spring Boot App for Maven Pre-Integration Test Phase

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, integration-testing, lifecycle

I have two spring boot apps, one contained in my src/test and one in my src/main.

I am using Maven verify to run SOAP integration tests. I have successfully booted my main app but also want to boot my test app pre-integration. I want to run the tests on my test app and then I need the main app to be open as well so it can connect to the SOAP endpoint.

When I run mvn verify, it starts up my main app in pre-integration and then runs ONLY my integration tests. Is it possible to launch another app? If yes, how do I configure it into my maven-springboot-plugin?

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE:start (pre-integration-test) @ billing_mediator ---

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.0.RELEASE)

2019-08-21 09:20:41.577  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] com.nulogix.billing.App                  : Starting App on Alexs-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 53762 (/Users/Alex/Documents/billing/billing_mediator/target/classes started by asluborski in /Users/asluborski/Documents/billing/billing_mediator)
2019-08-21 09:20:41.582 DEBUG 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] com.nulogix.billing.App                  : Running with Spring Boot v2.1.0.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.2.RELEASE
2019-08-21 09:20:41.585  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] com.nulogix.billing.App                  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-21 09:20:42.541  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'webServiceConfig' of type [com.nulogix.billing.ws.endpoint.WebServiceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ad324219] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-21 09:20:42.544  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$668ea787] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-08-21 09:20:42.593  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] .w.s.a.s.AnnotationActionEndpointMapping : Supporting [WS-Addressing August 2004, WS-Addressing 1.0]
2019-08-21 09:20:43.099  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 28443 (https)
2019-08-21 09:20:43.128  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-21 09:20:43.129  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.12
2019-08-21 09:20:43.144  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/asluborski/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2019-08-21 09:20:43.258  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-21 09:20:43.258  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1625 ms
2019-08-21 09:20:43.300  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet messageDispatcherServlet mapped to [/nulogix/ws/*]
2019-08-21 09:20:43.302  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2019-08-21 09:20:43.307  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-21 09:20:43.308  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-21 09:20:43.308  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'formContentFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-21 09:20:43.308  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2019-08-21 09:20:43.350 DEBUG 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : billing.engine.address=127.0.0.1
2019-08-21 09:20:43.351 DEBUG 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : billing.engine.port=9119
2019-08-21 09:20:43.351 DEBUG 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.b.service.PredictionEngineService    : Using http://127.0.0.1:9119
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector (file:/Users/asluborski/.m2/repository/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.11/jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.opt.Injector
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2019-08-21 09:20:43.847 DEBUG 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.api.version=0.97
2019-08-21 09:20:43.847 DEBUG 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.core.version=0.97
2019-08-21 09:20:43.848 DEBUG 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.billing.ws.endpoint.AnalyzeEndPoint  : billing.engine.core.name=Nulogix_Patient_Responsibility
2019-08-21 09:20:43.851 DEBUG 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] c.n.b.ws.endpoint.GetVersionEndPoint     : billing.engine.api.version=0.97
2019-08-21 09:20:44.099  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-21 09:20:45.055  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 28443 (https) with context path ''
2019-08-21 09:20:45.060  INFO 53762 --- [ling.App.main()] com.nulogix.billing.App                  : Started App in 4.044 seconds (JVM running for 13.722)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:integration-test (default) @ billing_mediator ---
```

EDIT:

So I edited my POM and added multiple executions like this(not sure if this is correct, can't find any documentation on how to do this for spring boot maven plugin)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
             <includePom>true</includePom>          
        </configuration>  
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
               <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.App</mainClass>   
                    </configuration> 

                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test2</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
               <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp</mainClass>   
                    </configuration> 

                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>

                         <goal>stop</goal>                  
                    </goals>
                     <configuration>
               <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.App</mainClass>   
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test2</id>
                    <goals>

                         <goal>stop</goal>                  
                    </goals>
                     <configuration>
               <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp</mainClass>   
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
```

This gives me an error though when it tries to start up my test server(MockServerApp).

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:436)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run (AbstractRunMojo.java:553)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:835)
```

Not sure why it is giving me this error since it is the correct class path and the class exists under src/test/java

EDIT:

I added this into configuration of plugin

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
             <includePom>true</includePom>      
             <additionalClasspathElements>
            <additionalClasspathElement>${basedir}/target/test-classes</additionalClasspathElement>
        </additionalClasspathElements>    
        </configuration>
```

but I get the same error.

Adding classpathscope also doesn't fix:

```
<execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test2</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

               <mainClass>com.nulogix.billing.mockserver.MockServerApp</mainClass> 
              <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
                    </configuration>                                      
                </execution>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the expected ordering ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel I want it to launch my test server(MockServerApp on 9119) and also launch my main app server (App on 28433) pre integration, then run the integration tests, and then both shutdown post-integration

Comment: Thanks, I think that you can achieve this by defining several execution of the spring boot plugin, to start and stop each application. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34189795/how-to-execute-a-maven-plugin-twice-with-different-property) to see how to do it. I cannot write a full answer right now

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel So I attempted a solution from the answer of the question you linked to. It was a different plugin but I tried to set separate executions. It seems to technically work as it tries to load my app but it gives me a class not found exception. I have edited my question with more information.